# Set selected value on dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have the below code, so the user can select the language he desire:

```
<label style="float: left; width: 50%;" for="system_language">Select Language:</label>
        <select id="system_language" class="selectbox float-right" onChange="switchLanguageLogin();  ">
        <? echo getLanguageList(); ?>

    </select>
```

This is the function of the languages!

```
function loadLanguage($lng, $units = '')
{
    global $ms, $la, $gsValues;

    // always load main english language to prevet error if something is not translated in another language
    include ($gsValues['PATH_ROOT'].'lng/english/lng_main.php');

    // load another language
    if ($lng != 'english')
    {
        $lng = $gsValues['PATH_ROOT'].'lng/'.$lng.'/lng_main.php';

        if (file_exists($lng))
        {
            include($lng);
        }
    }
```

Added the Language Function

```
function getLanguageList()
{
    global $ms, $gsValues;

    $result = '';
    $languages = array();

    $q = "SELECT * FROM `gs_system` WHERE `key`='LANGUAGES'";
    $r = mysqli_query($ms, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $languages = explode(",", $row['value']);

    array_unshift($languages , 'english');

    foreach ($languages as $value)
    {
        if ($value != '')
        {
            $result .= '<option  value="'.$value.'">'.ucfirst($value).'</option>';  
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The first (and default) option on the dropdown menu is English. The problem is that if I choose Spanish, it translates to Spanish, but on the dropdowm menu it leaves the default value which is English. This concludes that the page is in Spanish, but the value from the dropdown shows "English".

How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML generated by your `getLanguageList` function?

Comment: show us the functionality of `switchLanguageLogin();`

Comment: Save your selected language somewhere and set it accordingly in your options, probably your `getLanguageList()`.

Comment: Hello Guys,
I edit the question!

Comment: that function is no where used inside select code. so that function is not useful for us. Leave it as it is, but add `switchLanguageLogin()` function code. As well as `getLanguageList()` code too

Answer (score 2):

You do not use your `$lng` variable in the global scope, so it is not visible for your function. A solution would therefore be to provide the selected language as parameter to the `getLanguageList` function and set the equal value as selected:

```
function getLanguageList($selected = 'english') {
    //...
    foreach ($languages as $value) {
        if ($value !== '') {
            $result .= '<option  value="'.$value.'" ' . ($selected === $value ? ' selected="selected"' : ''). '>' . ucfirst($value) . '</option>';  
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Like this the selection is kept for the dropdown and therefore for the HTML.
In your view you would then need to provide `$lng` and call `<? echo getLanguageList($lng); ?>`.

Comment: To provide information about how to make your language variable accessible in your view we would need more information, like the framework you use on PHP side or your file structure and call hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your **init.php** file should have a comment

> // gets language from cookies

If there is not such comment, write it just before MySQL connection and add the following code after it

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['gs_language']))
{
    $gsValues['LANGUAGE'] = $_COOKIE['gs_language'];
}
else
{
    $expire = time() + 2592000;
    setcookie('gs_language', $gsValues['LANGUAGE'], $expire, '/');
}

// puts selected language into cookies
if (isset($_GET['lng']))
{
    $gsValues['LANGUAGE'] = $_GET['lng'];
    $expire = time() + 2592000;
    setcookie('gs_language', $gsValues['LANGUAGE'], $expire, '/');
}
```

Then go to **fn_common.php** file and change the getLanguageList function to

```
function getLanguageList()
{
    global $ms, $gsValues;

    $result = '';
    $languages = array();

    $q = "SELECT * FROM `gs_system` WHERE `key`='LANGUAGES'";
    $r = mysqli_query($ms, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $languages = explode(",", $row['value']);

    array_unshift($languages , 'english');

    $currentLang = $gsValues['LANGUAGE'];

    foreach ($languages as $value)
    {
        if ($value != '')
        {
            $result .= '<option  value="'.$value.'" ' . ($currentLang === $value ? ' selected="selected"' : ''). '>' . ucfirst($value) . '</option>';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```